# cakephp contain bringing back all results

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am using cakephp 2.5 and trying to get a contain to work

```
public function ajax($searchTerm = null)
    {
        $this->loadModel('Post');
        $posts = $this->Post->find("all", [
            'contain' => [
                'Comment' => [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'OR' => [
                            'Comment.content LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%"
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]);
        var_dump($posts);
        $this->set('posts', $posts);
    }
```

Is what I have so far with

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

In my AppModel.php

No matter what I do it just brings back all results in my post and not ones that contain the searchterm in an associated comment. I've read and reread the manual and Googled myself into frustration. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am attempting to build a search that will search for stuff in the posts or any related entities

Something like

```
 $posts = $this->Post->find("all", [
            'Post',
            'conditions' => [
                'OR' => [
                    'Post.title LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%",
                    'Post.body LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%"
                ]
            ],
            'contain' => [
                'Comment' => [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'OR' => [
                            'Comment.content LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%"
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]);
```

The first part works but again nothing from the contain.

Comment: Why are you using an 'OR' in your contains' conditions when you're only supplying one condition?

Comment: The best way to debug is to see the query generated, as explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521225/cakephp-get-last-query-run.

Comment: Anyway, try removing `'Post'` at the beginning of the options array, and the `'OR'` parameter in the comment conditions.

Comment: the problem is that posts hasMany comments. So cake does not joins the tables but  performs two separated queryes. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288416/creating-virtual-fields-on-the-fly-in-cakephp/19289460#19289460) if it can help

Answer (score 0):

I guess that a Post hasMany Comments.

Cake does not join the tables, so you have to join yourself.

You can use a `INNER JOIN` but the simplest way is to 'reverse' your query: search for all the `Comments` and their `Post` and then group by `Post.id` or `Comment.post_id`

```
$posts = $this->Post->Comments->find("all", [
    'conditions' => [
        'OR' => [
            'Post.title LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%",
            'Post.body LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%",
            'Comment.content LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%"
        ]
    ],
    'contain' => [
        'Post' 
    ],
    'group' => ['post_id']
]);
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve what you're trying to do. You can also find all the `post_id` of your matching comments and then find the Posts with a second query

```
 $comments = $this->Post->Comments->find("all", [
    'fields' => 'group_id',
    'conditions' => [
        'OR' => [
            'content LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%"
        ],
    ] 'group' => ['post_id']
]);

$post_ids = Hash::extract($comments, '{n}.Comment.post_id');

$posts = $this->Post->find("all", [
    'conditions' => [
        'OR' => [
            'Post.title LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%",
            'Post.body LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%",
            'Post.id IN' => $post_ids
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you understand the contain the wrong way (as I did).
You get all Posts anyway, but all comments which are not met the condition are skipped. That is the way how contain works.
If you want to have only the Posts which contains certain comments, then **you have to change to the Comments Model** and set the query.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
$posts = $this->Post->find("all", [
        'conditions' => [
            'OR' => [
                'Post.title LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%",
                'Post.body LIKE' => "%{$searchTerm}%",
                "Comment.content LIKE %$searchTerm%", // You perhaps need to escape $searchTerm here
            ]
        ],
        'contain' => ['Comment']
    ]);
```

> If you find yourself unable to form a `WHERE` clause, you can always specify it as a string.

[Source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Comment: this is unlike to work since cake does not join the tables when their relationships is hasMany (and I guess that a Post hasMany Comments)