# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TaskTags.id' in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have Three tables Projects, Tasks and Tags.  Projects.id is the primary key of the first table, Tasks.id is the PK of the second table and Tags.id is the PK of Third table.

```
$test = $this->Projects->find('all',
    array(
        'recursive' => 2
    )
);
```

Returns right data.

But

```
$test = $this->Projects->find('all',
       array(
          'recursive' => 2,
          'conditions' => array('Tags.id = ' => '10')
       )
    );
```

Gives below error.
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Tags.id' in 'where clause'.

I do have id field for Tags table, Why getting this error?

Projects Model Code snippet

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $hasMany = array(
    'Tasks' => array('className' => 'Tasks','foreignKey' => 'project_id')
);
```

Tasks Model Code snippet

```
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $hasMany = array(
    'Tags' => array('className' => 'Tags','foreignKey' => 'task_id')
);
```

Comment: you don't have collumn id in table Tags try ` Tags ` . ` id ` remove spaces, I'm insert for don write code.

Comment: and please show shema the database in table structure

Comment: change `'conditions' => array('Tags.id = ' => '10')` to `'conditions' => array('Tags.id' => '10')` and it will work.

Comment: Check **Containable** behaviour - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html for defining conditions on related models.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288416/creating-virtual-fields-on-the-fly-in-cakephp/19289460#19289460) can help

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can not pass condition on hasMany associated Model fields.

To make this work, pass "joins" in the Find condition, this will work fine.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html