# Select 2 columns with CakePHP 2

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp-3.0

Excuse me if the title doesn't suit my question.

I have a table named **Sales** and 3 columns named *Seller*, *Buyer* and *Price*.

What I have :
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tMIf.png)

What I want :
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTqH3.png)

Basically I want to display a list of sellers with the sum of the sales they have done with one buyer.

This is the SQL query I'm going with :

```
SELECT seller, buyer ,SUM(price)
FROM sales
GROUP BY seller , buyer
```

My problem (besides that this query is probably wrong) is the "translation" into CakePHP. After going through the cookbook, I have this in my controller :

```
public function myview (){    
$this->set('mysales', $this->Sales->find('all', 
array('sum(price) AS total','group' => array('seller','buyer'))));
}
```

I display the results in myview.ctp into a HTML table with PHP (I didn't put the HTLM elements below):

```
<?php
foreach ($mysales as $thesales)
    {      
        echo $thesales['Sales']['seller']; 
        echo $thesales['Sales']['buyer'];
        echo $thesales['Sales']['total'];
    }?>
```

Of course it doesn't work. I'm working with SQL Server 2014 and I have this error :

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'sales.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Thanks very much for your help !

Comment: Can you do a `debug()` on `Sales->find()`? It should include the generated query.

Comment: array(
 'Sales' => array(
  'id' => '1',                                  
  'price' => '100',
  'buyer' => 'mr.X',
  'seller' => 'mr.A'
 )
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL functions, you should follow this syntax: [Using SQL Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)

Try this:

For CakePHP 3:

```
$mysales =  $this->Sales->find();

$mysales =  $mysales 
    ->select([
        'seller', 'buyer',
        'total_price' => $mysales ->func()->sum('price'),
      ])
    ->group(['seller','buyer'])
    ->toArray();

pr($mysales); // Check your result
```

For CakePHP 2.x:

```
$this->set('mysales', $this->Sales->find('all', 
  array(
     'fields' => array('SUM(price) AS total','seller','buyer'),
     'group' => array('seller','buyer')
  )
));
```

In your view:

```
pr($mysales);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
The select doesn't seem to work, I have this error :
 Call to a member function select() on array

Comment: Have you followed the exact same syntax I've specified? Its not supposed to show such an error. You're using CakePHP 3, right?

Comment: I'm so sorry, my administrator told me it was Cakephp 3 but I just checked in the Version.txt and it says I have Cakephp 2.3.6

Comment: I've edited my answer for CakePHP 2.x. Please take a look.

Comment: I love you so much. The query works but the row "total" doesn't and this is because I'm dumb. 

The line on my table "echo $thesales['Sales']['total'];" is wrong because the variable total is not on my database but when I do this :
"echo $total" it give me "Undefined variable".

How can I display the total ?

Comment: To display the total, you need to write $thesales[0]['total'] instead of $thesales['Sales']['total'];

Comment: Thank you so much, lot of virtual hugs for you

Comment: @heisenberg remembre you can create virtualFields so you can access to the field using `$thesales['Sales']['total']`. See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288416/creating-virtual-fields-on-the-fly-in-cakephp/19289460#19289460)