# Cakephp query with WHEN CASE

Tags: cakephp, case

I have below query.

```
$parents = $this->SurveyQuestion->find('all',array('fields' => array( 
                       'SurveyQuestion.id', 
                       '((CASE WHEN SurveyQuestion.tree_label%2="" THEN \'tree_label\' ELSE \'label\' END)) AS plabel' 
                   ),'conditions' => 
                array('`SurveyQuestion`.`id` <>' => $id), 'recursive' => -1));
```

I want result like below.
I want result from tree_label column if it is not NULL else I want result from label column.
Above query returns wrong value.. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: what cake version?

Comment: This is version 2.x

Comment: see if this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288416/creating-virtual-fields-on-the-fly-in-cakephp/19289460#19289460

Answer (score 3):

Giving you an similar example, please try like this :

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN published = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS number_published,
COUNT(CASE WHEN published = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS number_unpublished
FROM articles

$query = $articles->find();
$publishedCase = $query->newExpr()
->addCase(
    $query->newExpr()->add(['published' => 'Y']),
    1,
    'integer'
);

$unpublishedCase = $query->newExpr()
->addCase(
    $query->newExpr()->add(['published' => 'N']),
    1,
    'integer'
);

 $query->select([
'number_published' => $query->func()->count($publishedCase),
'number_unpublished' => $query->func()->count($unpublishedCase)
]);
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: For more help:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements

Comment: This is the best answer for Cakephp 3. Although op explicitly ask for cakephp 2, is still helpful for us cakephp 3 users :)

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help you

```
$parents = $this->SurveyQuestion->find('all',array('fields' => array( 
                       'SurveyQuestion.id', 
                       '((CASE WHEN SurveyQuestion.tree_label%2="" THEN SurveyQuestion.tree_label ELSE SurveyQuestion.label END)) AS plabel' 
                   ),'conditions' => 
                array('`SurveyQuestion`.`id` <>' => $id), 'recursive' => -1));
```